# Share an object list externally using ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-sharing

I have a RecyclerView which needed to be sent/shared with external apps like WhatsApp etc. Using ShareActionProvider to achieve this. 
Have created a menu and inflated in the overflow area in ToolBar using SharedActionProvider.

sample code.

```
  public void prepareShareIntent() {

    shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sample Text.");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
}
```

If data sharing between internal activities, we usually pass objects/object list by serialising/ Parcelable or using gson , no issue here since we can easily parse the data in the receiving activity. But in case, if I need to share a list Object to external apps what should be done. Does the external apps interpret as only specific types?

Appreciate the possible approaches.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a RecyclerView which needed to be sent/shared with external apps like WhatsApp etc.

That is not possible. First, you cannot pass a `View` to another process. Second, WhatsApp and other apps would not know what to do with it.

> If data sharing between internal activities, we usually pass objects/object list by serialising/ Parcelable or using gson , no issue here since we can easily parse the data in the receiving activity.

You cannot convert a `RecyclerView` into a `Serializable`, a `Parcelable`, or JSON. You might be able to convert *the model data* that the `RecyclerView` uses into one of those things, but third-party apps (e.g., WhatsApp) may not know what to do with it.

> Does the external apps interpret as only specific types?

Correct. The MIME type of the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` needs to be the MIME type of the content shared via `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`.

I recommend that you spend some time thinking about what *exactly* you expect WhatsApp to do when you share content with it, where that content is somehow tied to a `RecyclerView`. For example, if you want WhatsApp to send a screenshot of the `RecyclerView` to somebody, then you should be sharing a screenshot of the `RecyclerView`, not the `RecyclerView` itself.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice answer. My scenario was to share the ticket booking details with the passenger list which I was wondering how they share it with WhatsApp to display as a message. Instead of converting RecyclerView to Serialise but trying to pass the Object list itself to the external apps. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: @user2695433: Perhaps generate some simple HTML (using tags supported by `Html.fromHtml()` and `Html.toHtml()`) and share the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the direction . That would be definitely worth a try .